# Loopback remote method called twice

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, vuex

This is my model and I have one remote method.

```
CustomUser.remoteMethod('uLogin', {
    accepts: [
        { arg: 'data', type: 'object', http: { source: 'body' } },
        { arg: 'req', type: 'object', http: { source: 'req' } },
    ],
    returns: { arg: 'result', type: 'object' },
    http: { verb: 'post' }
});
```

When I call POST uLogin, it gets called twice. I guess it's related with specifying source of each parameter.

```
CustomUser.uLogin = function(data, req, callback) {
    console.log('loggin in');
}
```

`Console` says:

```
logging in
logging in
```

Please help me!

Comment: I have solved issue myself. It was related with NGINX config.